# React Router - отрендерить элемент с нуля

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Делаю админку на реакте. Есть структура компонента App:

```
хэдер
сайдбар
свитч -> роуты, которые подружают страницы
футер
```

Все работает нормально, но сейчас я создал страницу логина (просто два поля и кнопка по центру), на которой нельзя показывать другие элементы (футер, сайдбар, хэдер).

Каким образом в роутах можно сделать рендеринг исключительно компонента login?

Comment: [Ссылка](https://coderoad.ru/43916689/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81-react-router)

Answer (score 1):

Убери layout на уровень ниже

```
App.js
<Switch>
      <Route path="/page" component={PageComponent} />
      <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
</Switch>
```

```
PageComponent.js
<PageHeader />
<PageSidebar />
<PageMainContent>
    <Switch>
          <Route path="/some-route" component={SomeComponent} />
          <Route path="/some-route2" component={SomeComponent2} />
    </Switch>
</PageMainContent>
```

Comment: Я так делал, но нужна ссылка не /page/users, а просто /users

Comment: Да и как оно будет работать, если /some-route уже не будет вызывать PageComponent в App.js

Comment: ты же будешь уже внутри компонента PageComponent

Comment: Каким образом?)
Ссылка http://localhost:3000/some-route не попадет в роут /page в App.js. А http://localhost:3000/page/some-route не попадет ни в какой роут.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, насколько идеологически правильно, но такой вот костыль **перед**  `return (<Router>...` подошел:

```
if(window.location.pathname === '/login') return <Login />
```